# How do I put a foreach loop inside of a XDocument in creation?

Tags: c#, asp.net, foreach, linq-to-xml

I have a small problem with an XDocument that I am creating. I am trying to use a foreach loop inside of the document creation, but I have no idea how to pull it off.
Code:

Some of the code:

```
XDocument doc = null;
            doc = new XDocument(

new XDeclaration("1.0", "ISO-8859-1", "no"),
        new XElement("data",

        new XElement("meta",

            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "printer"), DropDownPrinters.SelectedItem.Text),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "autoprint"), "YES"),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "test"), 0)
            ), //after this I need to loop through datarows, something like this

foreach (DataTable dt in ds3.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {

        new XElement("something",
            new XAttribute("something", dr.Field<string>("3")),

            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), dr.Field<string>("0") + " " + dr.Field<string>(4) + " " + dr.Field<string>(5)),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), dr.Field<string>("0")),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), dr.Field<string>("0")),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), dr.Field<string>("0")),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), "SE"),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"), dr.Field<string>("0")),
            new XElement("val",
                new XAttribute("n", "something"))
            );
}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use LINQ instead of `foreach`, something like this :

```
var something = from dt in ds.Tables.OfType<DataTable>()
                from dr in t.AsEnumerable()
                select 
                new XElement("something",
                    new XAttribute("something", dr.Field<string>("3")),
                    ......
                    ......
                );
```

Then you can put the variable, `something`, in the place where your `foreach` supposed to be.